# class construct,but now allocate memory

Tags: c++

```
template <class _T1>
inline void constructInPlace(_T1 *_Ptr)
{
    new (static_cast<void*>(_Ptr)) _T1();
}
```

I have known the place new about c++, I can't understand the above syntax!

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is known as [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new). It lets you construct objects in memory locations that you already own. It does NOT allocate memory for you.

In this case, a `T1` object is being constructed in the memory location pointed to by _Ptr, since `new` expects `void*`, it is being cast down. The cast would happen implicitly anyway, looks like the explicit cast is to make the intent clear.

Comment: oh,I have discover the new operator ( inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) throw() { return __p; })  but why expects void*?

Comment: When a memory location is just that a memory location and has no semantics about what it contains, it is typically expressed as `void *`because  it can contain anything, and does contain nothing

Comment: A typed pointer can be assigned to a void* pointer without using a type-cast, eg: `new (_Ptr) _T1();`

Comment: It would be implicitly cast down anyway right. Perhaps this was just to make the intent clear.